# How to set the body background for typo3 without or with extension?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I am using typo3 v9.5.0. I need to design a website with a background image wrapped all over the content element and menu. There is no specified layout in bootstrap package. I've tried extensions like [background](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/backgroundimage) by uploading the image.

[image]

But there is something wrong. By default its pointing the wrong resource which it left(typo3/01_DBM).

[image]
I have no clue why it's behaving like that. If there is any other extension or technique, kindly suggest me. But I want it to be done dynamically because it needs regular updation.

Comment: Could you add your site configuration (module site management > sites) ?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Yep.. I added it now only.. http://localhost/typo3/01_DBM as entry point. Still not getting it

Comment: there should be a misconfiguration or missing configuration somewhere that I cannot detect :( I tried to search for "Install TYPO3 on subfolder of localhost" but I obtained only very old results

Answer (score 1):

1. TYPO3 9.5.0 is outdated. although you use it localy update to current version.
2. you have multiple options to integrate a background image to the whole page.

Here my recommandation which does not require any specific extension:
As you use the bootstrap-package you can enhance the Fluid-templates of it in your own site-extension (which you should use).

**Where do you get the image from?**

Every `pages` record (defining a page in TYPO3) has fields for related media files (you can find/set it on the `Resources` tab.
Here an editor can easily insert an image which should be used as a background image to the content.

In your typoscript definition of variables for the page you can define an own variabel for the first image

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    [...]
    dataProcessing {
        111 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        111 {
            references {
                fieldName = media
                table = pages
            }
            as = BackgroundImages
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

and use it in the fluid template for the page like:

```
[...]
<div style="background-image:url(fileadmin/{BackgroundImages.0.originalFile.identifier});">
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid: '{data.uid}', colPos: '0'}" />
</div>
[...]
```

further enhancements could use a sliding mechanism, so a page without own background-image could use the image of parent page.

Comment: I think that the extension used here is pure TypoScript

Comment: the problem here is not the image itself but the site url: it is http://localhost/something/index.php while the images' url are http://localhost/fileadmin/image.png

Comment: then @mithun-jack should be more specific. then the problem shoould be solvable with `config.absRefPrefix` (preferable) or a `baseUrl`-setting.