# How/where to setup or edit extension path in typo3, in case of override?

Tags: jquery-plugins, typo3, typoscript

I am using typo3 8.7.29 version. I've installed a extension called [supersized](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/frsupersized) for jumbo sliders, also using bootstrap package 10.0.9. Plugin is working fine in the backend but the problem is it's failing to call the library because of my unnatural folder setup. For example, the library is calling js files in default order: http://localhost/typo3conf/ext/frsupersized/Resources/Public/Scripts/supersized/supersized-3.2.7/slideshow/js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js

[image]

But My files are in **localhost/htdocs/Typo_projects/project-folder/typo3conf/...** It might work if I switch the folder next to localhost. But I want the clear logic to make this thing work in the live server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generally working on a subfolder of your local installation, you should consider using this TypoScript option:

```
config.absRefPrefix = /htdocs/Typo_projects/project-folder/
```

If you only need this for your local environment, you can set the Application Context in e.g. Apache `SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development` and use a TypoScript condition:

```
[applicationContext = Development]
config.absRefPrefix = /htdocs/Typo_projects/project-folder/
[global]
```

Comment: link to docs for absRefPrefix in TypoScript documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#absrefprefix

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381311/how-to-set-the-body-background-for-typo3-without-or-with-extension/60389846#60389846) you have big problems defining your base folder for TYPO3 as you use subfolders of your webroot for your TYPO3 project.

In TYPO3 you can use `config.absRefPath` to define a subfolder of your webroot as base for any pathes in the frontend.

Another way would be to use the `base` tag to define it (but that could yield to other problems).

Try to set

```
config.absRefPath = /Typo_projects/project-folder/
```

in your basis typoscript setup.

Or use virtual machines with clean and simple configurations

Answer (score 0):

The question is: What is the document_root of your site?

If it is localhost/htdocs/ you have to change the path of the files in typoscript e.g. from
`/typo3conf/ext/frsupersized/Resources/Public/Scripts/supersized/supersized-3.2.7/slideshow/js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js`
to `/Typo_projects/project-folder/typo3conf/ext/frsupersized/Resources/Public/Scripts/supersized/supersized-3.2.7/slideshow/js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js`

I never did it like this. And I think it's much better to have the typo3conf folder (and the complete TYPO3 installation) directly in the document_root.

To change typoscript inside the backend look at the web section on left side and click on "Template", in the page tree click on your root site. In the dropdown field on the right side you will find the "Constant Editor" where you will find 'frsupersized'